# General .htaccess rewrite rules for multiple server directory configurations

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure on my local development web server:

```
/www
    /f3-app-1
        /application
        /config
        /core
        /resources
        /ui
        /index.php
    /f3-app-2
        ...
    /f3-app-3
        ...
```

I keep all of my web apps (f3-app-1, f3-app-2, ...) in sub-folders of the document root. I am accessing the app with `http://localhost/f3-app-1/` and I am not using any virtual hosts.

I need to redirect everything (except for files in `ui` and `resources`) to index.php. To achieve this I am using something like the following in .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/f3-app-1/ui/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/f3-app-1/resources/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

My hosting provider's production server is using virtual hosts to allow multiple websites. After transferring files to their web server I need to change the .htaccess file to something like:

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ui/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Is there any way to make these mod_rewrite rules to work relative to web application's or `.htaccess` directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `/f3-app-1` optional:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/f3-app-1)*/ui/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/f3-app-1)*/resources/
```

But this is bad practice.

The proper way to do it is to have virtual hosts on your development environment too. This will solve this, and any other issue related to paths in general.